# Как добавить гамбургер иконку с анмацией, только без тулбара?

Tags: android, material-design

Как добавить гамбургер иконку с анмацией, только без тулбара - на `FrameLayout`?

Сделал с тулбаром и сделал тулбар прозрачным, но все равно занимающее место остается, поэтому решил сделать на `FrameLayout`. То есть на месте тулбара должна быть какая та картинка, а гамбургер должен остаться...

Вот я хочу сделать как первый у меня щас получается как на втором!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не совсем понятно, где вы ее хотите размещать тогда?

Comment: Там же, в левом верхнем углу

Comment: иконку гамбургера добавлять точно так же, как и другую иконку.

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Из него неясно то, что вам надо над тулбаром что-то поместить

Comment: Вы хоть прототип какой покажите, а то вообще непонятно что о чём

Comment: а почему вы в toolbar не можете поместить ваш ImageView ?

Comment: Думаете так будет правильно?

Comment: Я об этом даже и не думал...

Comment: Так на картинке еще и будут кнопки

Comment: Вы были правы, я так и сделал, но еще одна проблемка..

Comment: Используйте `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных моментов часто используют просто прозрачный Toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам для вашего случая подходит Collapsingtoolbarlayout. Посмотрите в его сторону. Там toolbar по умолчанию в таком положении прозрачный